# Unable to open mht file in IE

Tags: python, email-attachments, mhtml

I am trying to extract the attachments from an email mht file and write to separte mht files.I used the code in this link [Extracting mht files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562803/extracting-different-content-type-of-mht-file-into-multiple-mht-file) to extract and write the attachments to a file.
Apparently I am unable to open the output mht files in the case of Content/Type: application/pdf and application/octet-stream. Below is the format of the output mht file which I am not able to open in IE. I am wondering why I am unable to open the file in IE. Any help or suggestions would be useful. Thanks.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/html";
 boundary="===============0805110039=="

--===============0805110039==
Content-Type: application/pdf
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <abcd.pdf>

<Payload>

--===============0805110039==--
```